# Converting from a Formula object to a list

Tags: r, parsing, for-loop, formula

In R, I would like to iterate over a formula object. R automatically converts a formula to a parse tree, so I see no reason why I shouldn't be able to iterate.

For example, `f <- ~x + y` has elements `f[[1]] = ~` and `f[[2]] = x + y`. However, `for(v in f) print(toString(v))` does not output

```
[1] "~"
[1] "+, x, y"
```

as I would expect it to. Instead, it gives the error `invalid for() loop sequence`.

If I need to do it manually, I could always use `for(i in 1:length(f)) print(toString(f[[i]]))` which does produce the correct output. However, I would like to know why the first method does not work.

Comment: try `for (v in as.list(f))`.

Comment: Just to expand slightly on Matthew's suggestion, the for loop only works if you can iterate over a list or vector, so you have to explicitly convert the formula object first.

Comment: The problem there is that I do not think R converts it correctly. The output for using that is

    [1] "+, -"
    [1] "+, -"

Comment: @joran thanks. @JonClaus if you do `for (v in as.vector(f, 'character'))`, you can cut out the `toString`.

Comment: @JonClaus I get the desired output you've posted in the question.

Comment: You're right. I had a small typo when I tried your suggestion.